# SSRS report RSWindowsNTLM authentication from application

Tags: oracle, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, oracle-apex

I am working on Oracle Apex application and I need some reporting in my application. I have reports created in SSRS reports. 
Now I JavaScript code which I am using to open SQL server SSRS report using below code

```
window.location.href = 'https://abc/Reports/Pages/Report.aspx?ItemPath= DReport';
```

Now problem is user is already logged in application now when he is redirected to SSRS report , SSRS again asks for credentials because in SSRS `RSWindowsNTLM` authentication is enabled

Now how do I bypass prompt on SSRS? 
How Can i authenticate link with `RSWindowsNTLM` from application?

Comment: refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52406458/sql-server-reportserver-service-keeps-asking-for-credentials-in-browser/52426163#52426163 Hope it helps